# R - Create multiple new columns using conditional statements

Tags: r

R - Create multiple new columns using conditional statements

I am wondering if there is a way to create multiple columns based on a condition(s).

For example below, I have a dataframe with data and I want to create two columns based on the based on ccy. One column is a gbp conversion rate of the ccy and the other is a cad conversion.

If I pipe the mutates I can get it to work but there is repetition (and in my real problem, I have a complex list of ifelse so repeating the code for every column would create a lot of repetition).

```
df <- structure(list(product = c('option', 'forward', 'forward', 'option'),
                 ccy = c('usd', 'usd', 'eur', 'usd'),
                 amount = c(1000, 2000, 1000, 5000)),
            .Names = c('product', 'ccy', 'amount'),
            row.names = c(NA, 4L),
            class = "data.frame")
df
  product ccy amount
1  option usd   1000
2 forward usd   2000
3 forward eur   1000
4  option usd   5000

df %>% mutate(gbp_amount = 
                  ifelse(ccy == 'usd', round(amount / 1.8, 2),
                         ifelse(ccy == 'eur', round(amount / 1.3, 2),
                                'not_converted'))) %>% 
    mutate(cad_amount = 
               ifelse(ccy == 'usd', round(amount / 0.85, 2),
                      ifelse(ccy == 'eur', round(amount / .7, 2),
                             'not_converted')))

  product ccy amount gbp_amount cad_amount
1  option usd   1000     555.56    1176.47
2 forward usd   2000    1111.11    2352.94
3 forward eur   1000     769.23    1428.57
4  option usd   5000    2777.78    5882.35
```

Is there a way to create multiple columns based on a single if condition?

E.g., something like this pseudo code...

```
df %>% ifelse(df$ccy == 'usd',
        (mutate(gbp_amount = round(amount / 1.8, 2)),
        mutate(cad_amount = round(amount / 0.85, 2))),
    ifelse(df$ccy == 'eur',
        (mutate(gbp_amount = round(amount / 1.3, 2)),
        mutate(cad_amount = round(amount / 0.7, 2))),
        'not_converted'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL-alike joins if you have many "equals" conditions.

I am using the `data.table` syntax but you could do this `dplyr` too:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

# add a row which cannot be found ("joined") to demonstrate missing rates
df <- rbind(df, data.table(product = "option", ccy = "aud", amount = 3000))
df

lookup <- data.table(ccy      = c("usd", "eur"),
                     gbp_rate = c( 1.8,   1.3),
                     cad_rate = c( 0.85,  0.7))
lookup
#    ccy gbp_rate cad_rate
# 1: usd      1.8     0.85
# 2: eur      1.3     0.70

df[lookup, `:=`(gbp_amount = round(amount / gbp_rate, 2),
                cad_amount = round(amount / cad_rate, 2)),
                on = "ccy"]
df
#    product ccy amount gbp_amount cad_amount
# 1:  option usd   1000     555.56    1176.47
# 2: forward usd   2000    1111.11    2352.94
# 3: forward eur   1000     769.23    1428.57
# 4:  option usd   5000    2777.78    5882.35
# 5:  option aud   3000         NA         NA
```

You have to sort the result as you like and mark the lookup errors (missing conversion rates) with another value than `NA` if you want (but not with the string `"not_converted"` like in your question since this would mix up the data type of the column - double vs character).

Answer (score 3):

Consider building a *rates* data set and merge with your original, avoiding nested `ifelse`:

```
rates_df <- data.frame(ccy = c('usd', 'eur'),
                       type = c('gbp', 'gbp', 'cad', 'cad'),
                       rate = c(1.8, 1.3, 0.85, 0.7),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    
rates_df

df %>% 
  inner_join(rates_df, by="ccy") %>%
  mutate(gbp_amount = ifelse(type=="gbp", round(amount / rate, 2), 0),
         cad_amount = ifelse(type=="cad", round(amount / rate, 2), 0)) %>%
  select(product, ccy, matches("amount")) %>%
  group_by(product, ccy, amount) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)

# # A tibble: 4 x 5
# # Groups:   product, ccy [?]
#   product   ccy amount gbp_amount cad_amount
#     <chr> <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 forward   eur   1000     769.23    1428.57
# 2 forward   usd   2000    1111.11    2352.94
# 3  option   usd   1000     555.56    1176.47
# 4  option   usd   5000    2777.78    5882.35
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a `for-loop` if you want to do multiple actions. @R Yoda's solution is probably better though. Like he said, I'd use NA rather than a character string so you aren't mixing data types in a vector, otherwise it'll default to character.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if(df$ccy[i] == "usd") {
    df$gbp_amount[i] <- round(df$amount[i] / 1.8, 2);
    df$cad_amount[i] <- round(df$amount[i] / 0.85, 2);
  } else {
    NA
 }
  if(df$ccy[i] == "eur") {
    df$gbp_amount[i] <- round(df$amount[i] / 1.3, 2);
    df$cad_amount[i] <- round(df$amount[i] / 0.7, 2);
  } else {
    NA
  }
}
```

Comment: You just converted a vectorized process to rowwise iteration!

Comment: Heresy, I know! User asked for a single `if` statement though, careful what you wish for.